# How does Ethernet interface appear in IP link command

Tags: linux, networking, boot, systemd, udev

I'm experimenting with Linux and am trying to understand the early boot process.  At least on the systems I've been playing with udev is the "module" that is discovering devices.  Once it is discovered however, somehow it gets "added" to the list of available interfaces and you can then do an "ip link set dev  up" command.  Until that step though it won't recognize the device name.

My question is where does this happen, and what command is used?

I know it happens after "early user space", since I added a hook to my initramfs image and am using "ip link" to dump the interfaces and only the loopback interface exists.

It must happen pretty early though and in my system environment there is a "device" entry as sys-subsystem-net-devices-ens33.device when I do a systemctl command.

Its not at all clear how that entry gets added into the list of devices or what commands it performs.

Thanks for any help, I've been poking around, but the details of this process have not been easy to locate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no command. It isn't done by userspace in the first place – it's done entirely by the card's Ethernet driver, which uses `register_netdev()` from the kernel's "net" subsystem to make a new interface appear.

The process is, roughly:

1. Kernel discovers a PCI or USB device, builds a "modalias" describing it, and sends a uevent announcing the device to udev. For example:

   ```
   ACTION=add
   DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3
   DEVTYPE=usb_device
   SUBSYSTEM=usb
   ...

   ACTION=add
   DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0
   DEVTYPE=usb_interface
   MODALIAS=usb:v0B95p1790d0100dcFFdscFFdp00icFFiscFFip00in00
   SUBSYSTEM=usb
   ...
   ```
2. udev receives the uevent, processes it according to rules (running helper tools, adding various metadata, creating symlinks) and sends it again, this time to various libudev-using programs.
3. One of the udev rules files, `80-drivers.rules`, handles uevents containing `MODALIAS=` and uses libkmod to load any kernel modules matching that alias. (In the past, it used to run `modprobe` for the module loading. You can still pass a modalias to `modprobe` or `modinfo`, though.)

   ```
   $ modinfo usb:v0B95p1790d0100dcFFdscFFdp00icFFiscFFip00in00
   filename:       /lib/modules/4.7.2-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/usb/ax88179_178a.ko.gz
   description:    ASIX AX88179/178A based USB 3.0/2.0 Gigabit Ethernet Devices
   alias:          usb:v0DF6p0072d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
   alias:          usb:v2001p4A00d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
   alias:          usb:v0B95p178Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
   alias:          usb:v0B95p1790d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
   depends:        usbnet,usbcore,mii
   ...
   ```

   So for this device, udev will load the `ax88179_178a` driver.
4. Whether the driver was loaded just now or had been already loaded previously, the kernel calls its `.probe` function to attach it to a specific device.
5. The driver's `probe` function does whatever chip magic is necessary to power up the device, initialize it, configure it, and finally call `register_netdev()` to create a real Ethernet interface for itself.

   (For USB devices, some drivers defer probing to the `usbnet` module, which is the one that does most of the standard USB work and creates an actual Ethernet interface, and only calls the main driver to do the hardware-specific magic.)

   ```
   Sep 04 21:25:11 kernel: ax88179_178a 2-1.3:1.0 eth1: register 'ax88179_178a'
   ↵ at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.3, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 8c:ae:4c:f4:06:33
   ```

Comment: Thanks for that thorough answer.  It looks like when I tried to look at the network interfaces, the kernel must not have probed the device driver.

Comment: The initramfs might not even have the driver. Usually it's built to only have the bare minimum needed to mount / and /usr, so it'll only include networking if your root filesystem is on NFS or such.

Comment: In some more investigation this weekend, I added the e1000 module to the MODULES list (using mkinitcpio since I'm playing with an Arch distribution), and it did find the network interface.  Unfortunately it came up as eth0, instead of ens33.  When it pivoted to the normal boot (initrd finishing and transitioning to the normal boot sequence), it would leave the link as eth0 if I had up'ed the link in a custom hook.   I looked at the udev rules and it wasn't at all clear where that was being done.  I don't want to impact normal user space because of actions in early user space.

Comment: eth0 is what the driver uses by default. The renaming to en* is handled in "/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules".